# Error running ADF Morena application?

Tags: java, glassfish, oracle-adf

I develop an application in ADF. Scanning documents using [Morena 6](http://www.gnome.sk/Twain/jtp.html). When I test on my PC everything works ok but when I switch on the GlassFish application server and start scanning the document I receive an error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: SK.gnome.twain.TwainManager.listSources()[LSK/gnome/twain/TwainSource;
 at SK.gnome.twain.TwainManager.listSources(Native Method)
 at SK.gnome.twain.TwainManager.selectSource(TwainManager.java:163)
 at beans.ImageBean.skenirajDokument(ImageBean.java:571)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that your Morena jar file is not cross platform? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.html